# SUM from Specific Date until the end of the month SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID   GROUPID    oDate       oValue
1    A          2014-06-01  100
2    A          2014-06-02  200
3    A          2014-06-03  300
4    A          2014-06-04  400
5    A          2014-06-05  500
FF. until the end of the month
30   A          2014-06-30  600
```

I have 3 kinds of GROUPID, and each group will create one record per day.
I want to calculate the total of oValue from the 2nd day of each month until the end of the month. So the total of June would be from 2/Jun/2014 until 30/Jun/2014. If July, then the total would be from 2/Jul/2014 until 31/Jul/2014.

The output will be like this (sample):

```
GROUPID   MONTH   YEAR   tot_oValue
A         6       2014   2000
A         7       2014   3000
B         6       2014   1500
B         7       2014   5000
```

Does anyone know how to solve this with sql syntax?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify your desired output? It would seem people answering have quite different ideas about what you actually want. Most likely it's a running sum or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to get this:

```
SELECT  T.ID,
        T.GroupID,
        t.oDate,
        T.oValue,
        ct.TotalToEndOfMonth
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TotalToEndOfMonth = SUM(oValue)
            FROM    T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.GroupID = T.GroupID
            AND     T2.oDate >= T.oDate
            AND     T2.oDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.oDate) + 1, 0)
        ) AS ct;
```

For your example data this gives:

```
ID  GROUPID ODATE       OVALUE  TOTALTOENDOFMONTH
1   A       2014-06-01  100     2100
2   A       2014-06-02  200     2000
3   A       2014-06-03  300     1800
4   A       2014-06-04  400     1500
5   A       2014-06-05  500     1100
30  A       2014-06-30  600     600
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f72/1)**

For future reference if you ever upgrade, in SQL Server 2012 (and later) this becomes even easier with windowed aggregate functions that allow ordering:

```
SELECT  T.*,
        TotalToEndOfMonth = SUM(oValue) 
                                OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID, 
                                                    DATEPART(YEAR, oDate), 
                                                    DATEPART(MONTH, oDate) 
                                        ORDER BY oDate DESC)
FROM    T
ORDER BY oDate;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29f72/2)**

**EDIT**

If you only want this for the 2nd of each month, but still need all the fields then you can just filter the results of the first query I posted:

```
SELECT  T.ID,
        T.GroupID,
        t.oDate,
        T.oValue,
        ct.TotalToEndOfMonth
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TotalToEndOfMonth = SUM(oValue)
            FROM    T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.GroupID = T.GroupID
            AND     T2.oDate >= T.oDate
            AND     T2.oDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.oDate) + 1, 0)
        ) AS ct
WHERE   DATEPART(DAY, T.oDate) = 2;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f72/3)**

If you are only concerned with the total then you can use:

```
SELECT  T.GroupID,
        [Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, oDate),
        [Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, oDate),
        tot_oValue = SUM(T.oValue)
FROM    T
WHERE   DATEPART(DAY, T.oDate) >= 2
GROUP BY T.GroupID, DATEPART(MONTH, oDate), DATEPART(YEAR, oDate);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f72/8)**

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but it the result is wrong. It should 2000 on the 1st record. Because it only calculate from the 2nd of june. Cheers,

Comment: I suggest to improve the answer, like the sample of my result. Then I'll mark your answer. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

If you want grouped per GROUPID, year and month this should do it:

```
SELECT 
    GROUPID, 
    [MONTH] = MONTH(oDate), 
    [YEAR]  = YEAR(oDate), 
    tot_oValue = SUM(ovalue) 
FROM your_table
WHERE DAY(odate) > 1
GROUP BY GROUPID, YEAR(oDate), MONTH(oDate)
ORDER BY GROUPID, YEAR(oDate), MONTH(oDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you have data for different years

```
Select YEAR(oDate),MONTH(oDate),SUM(Value) 
From #Temp
Where DAY(oDate)>1
Group By YEAR(oDate),MONTH(oDate)
```

Comment: Yes, I have data for different year also.

Comment: Then do you need sum for each year each month or you just need by month only?

Comment: sum for each year and month

Comment: @Haminteu: ok, so does my answer work for you? or you need any modification

Comment: You miss the GroupID mate, but this is ok. Thank you. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

This query produces required output:

```
SELECT GROUPID, MONTH(oDate) AS "Month", YEAR(oDate) AS "Year", SUM(oValue) AS tot_oValue
  FROM table_name
  WHERE DAY(oDate) > 1
  GROUP BY GROUPID, YEAR(oDate), MONTH(oDate)
  ORDER BY GROUPID, YEAR(oDate), MONTH(oDate)
```